# adding the items integer values in java

Tags: java, arrays, java-8

I have data on following pattern and I just want to add the number of similar items and stored in a List. Whereas , the items like `quantity= 1, ingredient=chicken, unit =kg` , 
The unit will be always **kg**.  I have `List<itemsDTO>`  I want to add similar items from this list. `[{1,"kg","chicken"} , {2.2,"kg","beaf"} , {0.25,"kg","chicken"}]`

```
public class itemsDTO {

    double quantity;
    String unit;
    String ingredient;

}
```

I have tried this code

```
        List<itemsDTO> itemsDTOList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < itemsDTOList.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < itemsDTOList.size(); j++) {

                if (itemsDTOList.get(i).getIngredient().equalsIgnoreCase(itemsDTOList.get(j).getIngredient())) {
                    int sum;
                    sum = itemsDTOList.get(i).getQuantity() + itemsDTOList.get(j).getQuantity();
                }
            }

        }
```

> Expected Output
>   1.25 kg chicken,2.2 kg beaf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `toMap` collector with merge function:

```
BinaryOperator<itemsDTO> sumQuantity = (a, b) -> {
        a.setQuantity(a.getQuantity() + b.getQuantity());
        return a;
    };
itemsDTOList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(itemsDTO::getIngredient, Function.identity(), sumQuantity))
    .values();
```

Comment: What is the `list` in your answer? @Hadi J

Comment: I meant `itemsDTOList`

Comment: It is possible that  I have `chicken` is more than 2 times. So, does it work for that condition too?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. `toMap` collectors  _with merge function_  merge all object with same `ingredient`

Comment: The resulted List will store in the same?  itemsDTOList?

Comment: I need to store it in List<String> after concatenation.

Comment: `List<String>` what is string value?

Comment: after the sum , it should store the sum particular items in `List<String>` as like "1.25 kg chicken,2.2 kg beaf"

Comment: It needs to concatenate `"summarized quantity" + " unit"+ "ingredient" `

Comment: you can do `itemsDTOList .stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(itemsDTO::getIngredient, Function.identity(), sumQuantity)).values()
                .stream().map(itemsDTO::toString).collect(Collectors.toList());` and override `toString` based on your willing.

Comment: @Lily, i think this solution is absolutely perfect. you should also try by yourself something. 
`itemsDTOS.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(ItemsDTO::getIngredient, Function.identity(), sumQuantity))
                .values()
                .stream()
                .map(itemsDTO -> itemsDTO.getQuantity() + " " + itemsDTO.getUnit() + " " + itemsDTO.getIngredient())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());` 
But above comment is perfect. you would call `itemDTO.toString` and override `toString` in your itemDTO class, which will return `quantity + " " + unit + " " + ingredient;`

Comment: @Shoshi yes its works 100%. Thank you Shoshi and Hadi J.